# Database has no tables but we are getting "No pending explicit migrations."?

Tags: entity-framework

We have entity framework migrations that create a few tables to setup an existing database. We ran the migrations once and they all ran but after looking at the database via SQL Server non of the tables that were supposed to be created were visible, even the Migration History table is not there.

We keep running the migrations again to see if we can create the tables but we keep getting the "No Pending Explicit Migrations" message.

Is there some other cache Entity Framework uses to figure out if Migrations have already run or not. How is it picking up that migrations have run yet the migration history table is not even there.

**My Execution Call:**
migrate.exe DllWithMigrations.dll /startUpConfigurationFile:"My Path\Web.config" /connectionProviderName:System.Data.SqlClient /connectionString:"My Connection String"

Comment: What does your connection string look like. Are you sure you are looking at the right database? Is Entity Framework using the connection string you think it is?

Comment: Yes when I use -verbose I get feedback that it is using the correct connection string to the correct database.